# modal dialog when the app load

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, material-design, angular-material

I have some questions about modal dialog:

**1. how I pass data to modal and return data from the modal?**

**2. I want to show the modal dialog when the app load and after he press on the button it go to the second page.**

let's assume that's my dialog.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pizza-component',
  template: `
  <button type="button" (click)="openDialog()">Open dialog</button>
  `
})
export class PizzaComponent {

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) { }

  openDialog() {
    let config = new MdDialogConfig();
    let dialogRef:MdDialogRef<PizzaDialog> = this.dialog.open(PizzaDialog, config);

  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'pizza-dialog',
  template: `
  <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  <p>Size: {{size}}</p>
  <button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close('yes')">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close('no')">No</button>
  `
})
export class PizzaDialog {
  name:string;
  size:string;
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<PizzaDialog>) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*how I pass data to modal and return data from the modal?* - 
There are great docs (https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog) about this.
Basically, you can set data from parent component to dialog component via setting the component instance. You can return the data from the dialog to parent component via dialog reference after closed method like this:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.selectedOption = result;
});
```

*I want to show the modal dialog when the app load and after he press on the button it go to the second page.* - You could call **open** method on dialog in the ngOnInit lifecycle hook.